# Updating SQL in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i want to update a date in the database under some condition, so i tried this method that i call it in button action performed

```
public void DeleteDate (JTextField txt1, JTextField txt2)
{
 try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String m = "IMCDietitian";
        String unicode= "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+m+""+unicode+"","root","");
        System.out.println("connected");
        String dept = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate("UPDATE "+dept+" SET edate = '"+jTextField1.getText()+"' WHERE pname = '"+txt1.getText()+"' AND rno = '"+txt2.getText()+"' AND edate = '-'");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't update any thing in the database. Can any one help me?

Comment: Do you see any exception? also i would suggest you use PreparedStatement as your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Warning, SQL injection... Use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @OP please meet [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @fge I see someone else's injection radar pinged.

Comment: No, there isn't any exception.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that and mishandling of resources too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be these reasons for not seeing any updates:

1. Perhaps the where clause does not result in any rows being returned therefore no row is updated.
2. Perhaps autocommit is false. In this case you would need to call commit explicitly. As a note, you could also take a look at transactions.
3. An Exception but it seems that in this case there is none.

Also, use PreparedStatement - it is cleaner and gets compiled for reuse.

Comment: The where clause read from textfield and the textfield get this text from the database. So the where clause must be in the database. For the autocommit, i tried conn.setautocommit(true); before creating the statment, but also it doesn't work. Can halp?

Comment: By specification auto-commit is already true for a newly created connection (as in the code of the question).

Comment: Do a test: get the value of variable "dept" and then do a select based on the same parameters as in the update SQL and check to see if anything is returned.

Comment: you are right, it doesn't read the text that it is in the textfield; i don't why. Now i will go to a another problem but thanks to make me look to the real error.